# Adding google groups to roles

Tags: google-app-maker

I feel like I'm missing something here, looking at the documentation on roles for App Maker this shouldn't be an issue.
[Add members to roles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eq2Sm.png)

However after testing this with a couple of different groups one created through GCDS (Active Directory group sync) and the other manually created through the G Suite admin panel and populated with two users neither the first or second groups members can access the deployed app. Are there any additional options that need to be checked on the group or in App Maker?

As an example:
[Group added to app and role](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgDjt.png) > [User added to group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGtmR.png) > [Error received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVv0l.png)

I have also tried allowing access for everyone in the domain and restricted creating records to the 'Accounting_Rep' role with the accounting@mydomain.com group assigned to the role the record isn't created and I receive a permissions error in stackdriver logging. It seems like App Maker isn't seeing it as a group.

Comment: If App Maker recognizes provided email as group it should show you group icon (https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qIG1.png). I don't see one on your screens what means that something went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely in `Application access` section you selected `Only allow access to specific users` option. In this case you need to explicitly add all users/groups you want App Maker to let in into the input box under the radio button group:
[image: Access settings]

Comment: Thanks Pavel, I've updated my original post to include a example and the response I get  when trying to access the app still no luck.

Comment: Hmm...that is strange. When did you sync/create those groups? Maybe it takes some time to propagate everything everywhere...

Comment: Years ago, however I just noticed this https://developers.google.com/appmaker/deployment#publish_an_application it says You can add Google Groups to this list if:

They belong to your domain. You cannot add a public group with a googlegroups.com address.
Your Google account has permission to view the Group's membership list. I have super admin rights so I would think this would be an issue.

Comment: This answer was correct however the developer account could not see members of the groups, adding the dev account and changing the setting on the group so members can view a list of members worked.