# Appmaker group access permissions for developer to add group to role

Tags: google-app-maker, google-groups-settings

I found some helpful information in this post [[Adding google groups to roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49573392/adding-google-groups-to-roles/51430901#51430901) ] which helped me realize I have to have permissions to at least read group membership in order to get a group to properly assign to a role under access permissions (or role assignment).  The only way I could get the small group icon next to the group e-mail address was to add myself (developer account) to that group.  I do not want to be added to every group in my domain which I assign to roles in my appmaker apps but I can't seem to find the right access permissions to grant access.

I have a second group which I have NOT added myself to but have allowed all in the organization to view members and members e-mail addresses.  Is there something I'm missing as appmaker does not appear to find the group (as indicated by the group icon) when adding it to a role?

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried. Have you checked the [AppMaker Define and Use Roles](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/security/secure-your-app#define_and_use_roles) which also covers permissions?

Comment: I get the same error as the other post: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVv0l.png even though I've added the "group" se-staff@domain.com to the role in the app settings under deployment.  The only way for the group to show up properly (i.e. with the group symbol: https://i.imgur.com/P8eVF7T.png) I have to add myself to the group.  When I add a group which the developer account is not in, the group appears as a single account (https://i.imgur.com/b0xi6zn.png).  Everyone in the domain is able to view the group membership and e-mail addresses but it will not respect the group for permissions.