# Correct Usage Of Groups For Permissions

Tags: google-app-maker

I have published a deployment that runs with the developer account. In the deployment settings I have a role called "Supervisors". I have assigned a google group to that role, directorssupervisors@domain.com.

[image]

When the deployment runs with the developer account, everythings works fine. But when the deployment is ran by any other user, I get the following error:

> appmaker.application.permission.GroupsPermission: Error reading group directorssupervisors@domain.com. Note: The deployer developeraccount@domain.com must have access to this group.
>   Exception:
>   Exception: You do not have permission to view the member list for the group: directorssupervisors@domain.com

The group settings are configured so that everyone in the domain can view the membership; moreover, the developer account is a member of the group.

I have checked the information provided [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51431318/appmaker-group-access-permissions-for-developer-to-add-group-to-role) and also [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49573392/adding-google-groups-to-roles/51430901#51430901) but none of them seem to help. The developer account was added to the group more than 72 hours ago and the deployment was published more than 48 hours ago.

So far, everything is leading me to believe this is a bug. Before I open a support ticket with the G Suite AppMaker team, I would like to know if anyone has had the same issue and if there was a solution to it.

Thanks in advance for your help!

**UPDATE**:
Now it is also showing the error when the app is ran by the developer account!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It so happens that the AppMaker team corrected a buggy behavior that allowed the reading of email addresses from groups without having the permission properly set up in the group settings. To make the app work again I had to make sure the group permission had the proper access for viewing email addresses; **Group Settings -> Permissions -> Access permissions -> View Email Addresses**.

Once I changed the permission to **All members of the group**, I proceeded to republish the app and then it worked again.

---

**Update 12/31/2019**

On top of the already mentioned above, you also need to make sure that the group is visible to all members in the organization:

**Group Settings -> Permissions -> Basic permissions -> Group Visibility**.