# How do you restrict a Google App Maker application so that only users in a Google Group can access it?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

I have built a Google App Maker application and published it. However, I only want users in a Google Group to be able to access the application (view UI elements) via the deployment link. How do you do this? I referenced this solution to another post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49577258/9878092. I cannot seem to find where the Application access section that is mentioned in the solution is. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the steps you can follow to go to 'Application Access' screen.

1. From your appmaker window click on 'Setting' icon. [image]
2. Go to Deployments tab.[image: Deployment]
3. Publish new deployment if you haven't done already. If you have already deployed your changes then click on the deployed version and "Edit" button.[image: Application Access]
4. This will open the Application Access screen. Select option "Only allow to specific" users. Provide user names who should be able to access the app.

Comment: If I only provide the Google Groups email, will that enable all members to access the application?

Comment: No Eric, unfortunately that's the limitation with appmaker currently. You need to provide user names only and not group names.